# How to compile Python to DLL or alternative?

Tags: python, dll, compilation, pyinstaller, nuitka

##### How to compile Python project?

I have a large Python project consisting of multiple scripts and importing some heavy libraries like PyTorch.

I need to use this project as a part of the final solution made in .NET.

Moreover, it should be **standalone** and **distributable**, since setting up a Python environment on the customer's side is not an option.

The best way is to be able to make a **DLL** or **static library**, but any alternative way such as **executable** works just fine.

---

##### What I have already tried.

###### Compilers

PyInstaller, Nuitka.

In both cases, I have encountered some dead-end issues with one or more packages. E.g. Nuitka failing with PyTorch

###### RPC

There is the prototype of the final solution which relies on RPC communication between running Python and .NET programs.

But distribution and source code protection are unresolvable issues with the architecture.

---

**Update:**
The target platform is Windows

Comment: I will wait to get an answer to this question too. I faced a similar situation and my solution was to rewrite the whole code in C++. Including related functions from scipy.

Comment: Thank you for your interest. I have thought about migrating the whole code to C++ or C#, but it seems currently unfeasible.

Answer (score 1):

you can try py2exe, pyinstaller:

**Step 1.** `pip install pyinstaller.`

**step 2.** new python file let's name it `code.py` .

**step 3.** Write some lines of code i.e print("Hello World")

**step 4.** Open Command Prompt in the same location and write pyinstaller code.py hit enter. Last Step see in the same location two folders name build, dist will be created. inside dist folder there is folder code and inside that folder there is an exe file code.exe along with required .dll files

Comment: As I have mentioned I already tried multiple compilers, including **Nuitka** and **PyInstaller**. They both seem to have issues with the **PyTorch**.